# Return shorthand if assignment is false in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, return, coalesce, shorthand

In a JavaScript function I would like to return if a given value is null.

While this works:

```
const A = this.B;

if (!A) {
   return;
}

// More code...
```

I would like to know if there's a simpler form to do this:

These don't work:

```
const A = this.B || return;

// More code...
```

```
const A = this.B;
                                                                                   
!A || return;

// More code...
```

Is there a possible shorthand for this?

Comment: Why `return` if `void 0` is returned? I would reverse the logic: `if (A) { // things... }`. The return is otherwise implicit.

Comment: You can't include a statement into an operand, that's why the second example doesn't work. What's the point of finding a shorthand? Don't minimize your developement code, a minifier will do it for you when creating production code.

Comment: do you have some code after `if`?

Comment: You can use one-line `if`. In your second examples, instead of `!A || return;` use `if (!A) return;`

Comment: @briosheje This is because those are checks, there are multiple checks in the code, where it would return. Code is clearer by adding conditions at the beginning and returning if any fail.

Comment: @JanStránský I can't use single line if statements because of company code convention.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, there are more code. I updated the question.

Comment: @pamoka I would personally avoid tu use a return statement when it's not at the end of the method. That's actually my opinion, so feel free to disagree, but the return statement should be at the end of the method in order to make it easier to mantain code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such shorthand. `return` is a statement, not an expression, and the only way to evaluate statements conditionally is `if`. Operators (AND, OR, ternary and so on) can help you evaluate expressions, but not statements

Answer (score 0):

**Depending on actual code**:

- if it just returns or should return a value
- on how many places
- what code is before (e.g. variables to be used further)
- what code is after
- etc. etc...

the following approach can be used.

Instead of `if (!A) return;` or (not working) `!A || return;`, you `return !A || theRestOfTheCodePutIntoAnotherFunction();`

An example of "original" code:

```js
class Test {
    constructor(b) {
        this.b = b
    }
    test() {
        const a = this.b
        if (!a) {
            return
        }
        console.log("TEST")
    }
}
console.log("test 0")
new Test(0).test()
console.log("test 1")
new Test(1).test()
```

and modified version

```js
class Test {
    constructor(b) {
        this.b = b
    }
    test() {
        const a = this.b
        return !a || this.test2()
    }
    test2() {
        console.log("TEST")
    }
}
console.log("test 0")
new Test(0).test()
console.log("test 1")
new Test(1).test()
```